# How to update VueJS left panel user list while update user information from right panel

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a VueJS application where I have a user's listing and user's information.

I am using two columns layout so in a left panel I am loading user's listing and when I click to any user, user's information will be loaded to the right panel.

I can view and edit the user's information from the right panel.
But updated information is not reflected in the left panel. For example, if I will edit the first name and last name of any user then it should be updated in the left panel but I don't know how can I do it in VueJS.[image]

index.vue

```
<template lang='pug'>
  two-col-layout(v-loading='loading', :show-edit-view='isAddOrEdit', default-text='Select Employee')
    template(slot='col-left-header')
      el-input(
        v-model='employeeSearchInput',
        placeholder='Search Employee by Name or Email',
        prefix-icon='el-icon-search',
      ).w-100.input-border-0

    template(slot='col-left-body')
      .fab.fab-rb
        el-tooltip(content='Add Employee')
          el-button(
            v-if='addUserPerm',
            type='success',
            circle,
            icon='el-icon-plus',
            @click='$router.push("/employees/new")',
          ).btn-fab

    template(slot='col-left-body-list')
      router-link(
        :key='employee.id',
        v-for='employee in filteredItems',
        :class='{ active: $route.params.employeeId === employee.id }',
        :to='`/employees/${employee.id}/edit`',
      ).list-group-item.list-group-item-action.d-flex.border-0
        .mr-11
          employee-avatar(
            v-if='employee.userPhoto',
            :image='employee.userPhoto',
          ).size-42
          employee-avatar(v-else, :email='employee.email').size-42
        .flex-1.d-none.d-md-block
          .fw-b {{ employee.firstName }} {{ employee.lastName }}
          .fs-14 {{ employee.email }}
          ul.list-unstyled.fs-14.mb-0
            li(v-for='team in employee.teams' :key='team.id').d-flex.mb-1
              .col-min-max.min-w-100.max-w-180
                | • {{ team.team.groupName }}
              .pl-3
                el-tag(
                  size='mini', :type='getRoleTagColor(team.role.roleName)'
                ).el-tag-for-role.fs-12
                  | {{ team.role.roleName }}
</template>
```

Edit.vue

```
<template lang='pug'>
  two-col-layout-edit(:loading-child='loadingChild', theme-color='#ffaeaf')
    template(slot='header-pic')
      employee-avatar(
        v-if='employee.userPhoto',
        @fileSelected='handleFileSelect($event)',
        :image='employee.userPhoto',
        show-uploader,
      ).size-100
      employee-avatar(
        v-else,
        :email='employee.email',
        @fileSelected='handleFileSelect($event)',
        show-uploader
      ).size-100

    template(slot='header-text') {{ employee.firstName }} {{ employee.lastName }}

    template(slot='main-content')
      el-form(
        ref='editEmployee', :model='employee', label-position='top', :rules='rules',
        @submit.prevent.native='validateEditEmpForm("editEmployee")'
      )
        h4.mb-4 Employee Information
        .row
          .col-md-6.col-xl-3
            el-form-item(label='First Name', prop='firstName')
              el-input(v-model='employee.firstName' :disabled="fncheckPerm()")
          .col-md-6.col-xl-3
            el-form-item(label='Last Name', prop='lastName')
              el-input(v-model='employee.lastName' :disabled="fncheckPerm()")
          .col-md-6.col-xl-3
            el-form-item(label='Email', prop='email' )
              el-input(v-model='employee.email' :disabled="fncheckPerm()")
          .col-md-6.col-xl-3
            el-form-item(label='Phone', prop='mobile' )
              el-input(v-model='employee.mobile' :disabled="fncheckPerm()")



    template(slot='footer-content')
      .col-auto
        el-button(type='danger', plain @click='removeUserConfirm()') Remove Employee
      .col-auto.ml-auto
        el-button(type='default' @click='cancelConfirm()') Cancel
        el-button(type='success' @click="validateEditEmpForm('editEmployee')") Save

    // things defined below will render in default slot
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use component communication to achieve what you want.

[Component communication with VueJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYe5g.png)

In application the data you are using on the left panel came from a prop of your parent element (which is parent of both left and right panels). When you update data on the right panel, update the root data so that the left panel will automatically re-render the changed data.

With this method, your data will always be in sync in both of your panels :)

[Pardon my paint :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLNoS.png)

So your root have you data, pass it to left and right child with props. When you select one in the left panel, use `$emit` to send message to parent that will then change data passed to right element.
In the same way, do this in the right component when you save your new data, send message to root that will update left component prop accordingly.

Component communication docs :

https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

https://medium.com/js-dojo/component-communication-in-vue-js-ca8b591d7efa

Comment: Okey, let me know if it helped you to fix your problem